# Eidim Zommemin on Sotah?

Tags: edim-witnesses, tractate-sotah, tosefta, sotah

[Tosefta Sotah 2:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Tosefta_Sotah.2.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) notes the Halacha of the Korban of a Sotah who was made a sotah by Eidim Zommemin.

I am wondering what their punishment would be.

Seemingly, there should be lashes.

Is it possible to give them lashes, or is it limited to a few cases (See Mishnah Makkot, 1, 1)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Rambam Hilchot Edut 21:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Testimony.21.5?lang=bi) states that *edim zomemim* on *kinui ustirah* receive lashes.

If they testified that she had in fact committed adultery, then they pay the value of her *ketubah* and are not given lashes.